# Use angular2 property usehash conditionally

Tags: angular

I want to set the value of *useHash* to true or false conditionally. so I created an exported function and called it in the app-routing module like this

```
 @NgModule({
      imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules, 
                                                useHash: AppHashingStrategy() })],
      exports: [ RouterModule ],
    })

export function AppHashingStrategy() {
    const result = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') !== -1 &&
                    window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('9.0') !== -1;
    return result;
}
```

The condition is if the browser is IE 9 then useHash = true otherwise false. This is because my angular2 app is not working in IE9 (shows loading... and hangs). But when I change the value useHash to false it starts working fine. so I want to set its value conditionally.

But when I do this I get error:

**Calling function 'AppHashingStrategy', function calls
 are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function**

how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

> Calling function 'AppHashingStrategy', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function

AS I know you face above error because lambda expression are not working with IE9.
I have used lambda expression with IE11 and it works fine.

Comment: Hi Sandip - It's not even a lambda expression it's a simple function call. How did you make it work for IE9?

Comment: I have given answer as per your error. Try to check for each object at which instance it not work like first check window then navigator then userAgent and so on. may be you find other property equivalent to it.

Comment: Sorry What is the answer? I want it to work with IE9... The issue is not navigator or window or userAgent... The issue is that I can't call a function in the imports...Is there any other way it could be called so I can check condition first and return true/false.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's 4 years later... I can't be sure of your exact situation. Especially now that we're on a different version of Angular and your project is probably long-gone. And especially since I can't test in IE.  But I can take a few guesses.

1. `useHash: AppHashingStrategy()` perhaps should be `useHash: AppHashingStrategy` instead.  In the first, you're passing the calculated value (which might not work in the Decorator).  In the second, you'd be passing the function itself, which gets called later.

   - It says "Function calls are not supported.  Consider ... a reference to an exported function."
   - Decorators are ran at compile-time, not run-time, so it makes sense that decorators would not support calling the function ahead of time.
2. Alternatively, it may be that the Options Object can't have functions in place of values, and you may need to pass in a function which returns the whole options object.

I think it's number 1., but I can't say for certain.